# Who Generates parameters G & H for Pedersen commitment in Monero?

Tags: cryptography, elliptic-curve, trustless-system

Who (which party) generates parameters G & H for Pedersen commitment in Monero? I mean for a confidential transaction in Monero, pedersen commitment is required which has parameters G & H which are group elements. I am not sure who generates it? Is trusted setup assumed?

Answer (score 3):

`G` is a universally agreed-upon base point. Almost everyone that uses ed25519, including Monero, uses the same `G`.

`H` is an agreed-upon base point within Monero's implementation of the Pedersen commitment scheme. It is chosen arbitrarily such that it is impossible to know the discrete log with respect to `G` (i.e. there is some `x` such that `xG == H`, but `x` will never be known).

The security of Pedersen commitments relies on `x` being unknowable.

Bottom line: All Monero wallets and daemons use the same values of `G` and `H`.